# Do I need multilevel modeling for the data with a small number of clusters + an imbalance in cluster sizes?

Tags: multilevel-analysis

My data is organized in nested levels: 48 children (individual-level) nested in 3 schools(cluster-level): n=30 in cluster 1, n=15 in cluster 2, and n=3 in cluster 3.

I simply wonder if I will need to use multilevel modeling for this small data set, which has only 3 clusters and is imbalanced in the cluster size. If there are more suitable analytic approaches for this dataset, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.